# Pointer to implementation pattern

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to implement the pointer to implementation pattern with template classes, and, in order to make independent class and its implementation, I use the next approach:

```
template<typename T>
struct __A_impl;

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using __impl_t = __A_impl<T>;

    A(__impl_t* t);

    __impl_t* _t;
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    T _t;
};

template<typename T>
using __A_impl = B<T>;
```

With this form, if I want to change the name of 'B', this doens't affect in any way the definition of A. But, I receive the next error with gcc:

```
test.cpp:21:22: error: declaration of template 'template<class T> using __A_impl =    B<T>'
test.cpp:2:7: error: conflicts with previous declaration 'template<class T> class __A_impl'
test.cpp:21:22: error: redeclaration of 'template<class T> using __A_impl = B<T>'
test.cpp:2:7: note: previous declaration 'template<class T> class __A_impl'
```

How can I achieve this? Because with a `typedef` declarator isn't possible.

Comment: The name of `__A_impl` invokes undefined behavior, because you are using compiler reserved words.  Same with `__impl_t`.  If you don't know the reserved word rules of C++, simply do not start any identifier with an underscore, and never have two underscores in a row, and you'll be (mostly) safe.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot forward declare a typedef. You can only forward declare classes/structs/enums.

Also, PIMPL is usually used to prevent the compiler from seeing the implementation, but in your case that's never going to happen because it's a template, so I don't see the point.

Comment: In my case, I don't want the "user" who uses my classes knows implementation details when he sees the class definition.

Comment: He already does- it's implemented with PIMPL, so he just finds the implementation type and done. You can't hide the implementation of a template type from a remotely intelligent user.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this compiles, although it might not be what you want:

```
template<typename T>
struct B
{
    T _t;
};

template<typename T>
using __A_impl = B<T>;

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using __impl_t = __A_impl<T>;

    A(__impl_t* t);

    __impl_t* _t;
};
```

Anyway, two things:

1. Why not just use `std::unique_ptr`?
2. Double underscores are reserved for implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: In my real code, each class name with double undercores are inside a namespace, so, there shouldn't be any problem. And respect to the unique_ptr, I have perfectly controlled the use of the pointer, so, perhaps unique_ptr creates more problem in other points of my implementation code.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Double underscore is reserved in all scopes (think about cases with macros). I don't understand what you mean about `unique_ptr`. Why wouldn't you have control of it?

Comment: Hehe sorry, my English isn't so good. The short version of my answer is that I don't see indeed a really good reason to use unique_ptr in my concrete case.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Yes, it is obvious that you cannot see the really good reasons to use `unique_ptr`, because you didn't use it.  A ridiculous number of C++ bugs are due to not handling memory lifetime properly, and if you think you are immune to that problem, then you are almost certainly wrong.